# Rails won't install in any way possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting to lose my mind, i spent 2 days trying to install rails and run a server but i'm still getting errors. When I try to install rails i get this error:

```
0 [main] locale (8428) shared_info::initialize: size of shared memory region changed from 51128 to 40888
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
  0 [main] make (12688) shared_info::initialize: size of shared memory region changed from 51128 to 40888
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

make
  0 [main] make (12688) shared_info::initialize: size of shared memory region changed from 51128 to 40888
```

I tried to update my system with gem update:

```
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.1.4
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `source_paths' for #<Gem::Specification:0x98bb1dc rubygems-update-3.1.4>
```

I also used 2 different ways to install ruby on rails from installrails.com (following the steps), and installing ruby and then installing rails by gem install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails on Windows does not work well. The further you get, the more problems you will face if you continue to develop it on Windows (for example, binaries of some gems wouldn't compile and so on).

I recommend you to use docker for it. It is simple and it would give you valuable skills. Here is the [link](https://medium.com/@tehn00b/developing-ruby-on-rails-in-docker-under-windows-99962999dd02) to start.

Another way would be to use a virtual machine and it seems to be recommended by gorails community. If you prefer this, here is the [link](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try with docker cause i worked with it before. But how come it is so bugged on windows?

Comment: I think because Ruby in general is not really made for Windows and the ruby community does not really use Windows for work